# Running AVRStudio 32 and JTAGICE MKII on Vista 64

Tags: avr, windows

I've attempted installation of AVR studio 32 (for AVR32 UC3 development) and it doesn't appear to work.

Has anyone here gotten this to work in Vista 64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I use a virtual machine running XP...

I notice that Dean Camera (a regular over at AVRFreaks) has been playing with getting AVR tools to work on x64 boxes. See this posting on his blog: http://fourwalledcubicle.com/blog/archives/467. He also mentions that he's recently installed a beta of AVR Studio ([http://www.atmel.no/beta_ware](http://www.atmel.no/beta%5Fware)) which supports Windows 7 and x64.

Comment: Which virtual machine will allow the USB JTAGICE to run from the XP image?

Comment: I don't use a USB JTAGICE but VMWare Workstation supports every other USB device I've ever tried with it and I'd be surprised if it didn't work with that one; it's just a USB device after all...